# SMS sending through ASP.Net API

Tags: c#, asp.net

The SMS Service provider gave a link to send the SMS. this link I put it in my website,But In That Link I have to pass the phone Number and Price dynamically through Label. Can anyone please help Me.
 I am Using The Code Which is

```
var cli = new System.Net.WebClient();
string price = "230";
string number = "9999999999";

cli.DownloadString(@"http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=ABCXYZ&pass=*****&sender=BSHSMS&phone=9999999999&text=Test SMS YOUR Order HAs Been Placed OF RS. 230 Successfully&priority=ndnd&stype=normal");
```

Comment: can you provide an exampe of what the expected outcome would look like? is the problem simply building a string to pass do `cli.DownloadString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put the stuff at the corresponding places in the string to pass to `cli.DownloadString()`. This examople shows how to do so using `string.Format()`

```
var cli = new System.Net.WebClient();
string price = "230";
string number = "9999999999";

var format = @"http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=ABCXYZ&pass=*****&sender=BSHSMS&phone={0}&text=Test SMS YOUR Order HAs Been Placed OF RS. {1} Successfully&priority=ndnd&stype=normal"

cli.DownloadString(string.Format(format, number, price));
```